# How do I download a file in react when server returning a gzip file?

Tags: reactjs, gzip

I want to download a gzip file from the server. I have an API that returns a gzip file. So I have to call that API from React and download the gzip file from the client-side.

Here is the code I have called the API:

```
const res = await API.get(`${baseUrl}/${advId}/${type}`, {
  params: { campaign_id: id, start_date: startDate, end_date: endDate },
});

const data = res.data;
const url = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob(data));
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
link.click();
```

Tried to convert the response from the server into Blob. But the error was **Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to construct 'Blob': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence.**. the response data should be a gzip file.

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working for you?

Comment: Tried to convert a response from the server into Blob. `const url = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob(response.data));` but the error was **Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to construct 'Blob': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence.** . the response data should be a gzip file.

Comment: You should edit your question and add that in.  Also, show the whole snippet where you make the call to the API.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 things you may try:

- if you are using axios, make sure to set the responseType to arrayBuffer `` axios.get(`${baseUrl}/${advId}/${type}`, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }) ``
- use an array to create your Blob, as such `new Blob([response.data])`

Comment: It's not working, is it possible to download the file without creating the blob?

Comment: Maybe, but I've always done file downloads in React this way and it has always worked. Perhaps you could add the full get request or the name of the library you are using to help identify your problem?